# Some question about sine functions

Tags: calculus

Let $x \in [0, \frac \pi 2]$ and $I_n$ be a length of intervals in which $\sin 4nx \leq \sin x$. Find a limit of $I_n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I tried to represent intersecting points of two sine functions implicitly but it is too hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a little result: Suppose we have $c \in [0,1]$ and the function $f_n(x) = \sin (4nx)$. Now compute the length of the set $J=\{t \in [0, {\pi \over 2 n}] | f_n(t) \le c \}$; it is straightforward to get $m(J) = 2 {1 \over 4n} \arcsin c + { \pi \over 4n}$. Note that this length is the same if we take $t \in [k {\pi \over 2 n}, (k+1){\pi \over 2 n}]$ instead.

Let $J_{k,n}(c) = \{t \in [k {\pi \over 2 n}, (k+1){\pi \over 2 n}] | f_n(t) \le c \}$, and note that if $c \le c'$, then $J_{k,n}(c) \subset J_{k,n}(c')$. Also, as above, note that $m(J_{k,n}(c)) = 2 {1 \over 4n} \arcsin c + { \pi \over 4n}$, which is increasing as a function of $c$.

Let $I_{k,n} = \{ t \in [k {\pi \over 2 n}, (k+1){\pi \over 2 n}] | f_n(t) \le  \sin t\} $, and note that
$J_{k,n}(\sin(k {\pi \over 2 n})) \subset I_{k,n} \subset J_{k,n}(\sin((k+1) {\pi \over 2 n}))$, and hence
$2 {1 \over 4n} \arcsin (\sin(k {\pi \over 2 n})) + { \pi \over 4n} \le m(I_{k,n}) \le 2 {1 \over 4n} \arcsin (\sin((k+1) {\pi \over 2 n})) + { \pi \over 4n}$, or, simplifying a little, we have:
${1 \over 2} {\pi \over 2n}({k \over n}+1) \le m(I_{k,n}) \le {1 \over 2} {\pi \over 2n}({k+1 \over n}+1) $.

Now take sums to get
$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over 2} {\pi \over 2n}({k \over n}+1) \le m(I_n) \le \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {1 \over 2} {\pi \over 2n}({k+1 \over n}+1)$, and note that if we let $\phi(x) = {1 \over 2} ({2 \over \pi}x+1)$, we can rewrite this as
$  L(\phi,P_k) \le m(I_n) \le   U(\phi,P_k)$, where $L,U$ are the lower and upper Riemann sums respectively, and $P_k$ is the partition $(0,{\pi \over 2n},...,k {\pi \over 2n},...,{\pi \over 2})$.

Since $\phi$ is Riemann integrable, we have $\lim_n m(I_n) =   \int_0^{\pi \over 2} \phi(t)dt = { 3 \pi \over 8}$.

Comment: What a incredible idea...

Comment: Not as incredible as it seems. There is an old control system trick called dithering which uses a signal (the $\sin(4nx)$ above) along with an input (the $\sin x$ above) and a small amplifier driving a switch that produces a PWM-like output (which would be represented by the $I_n$ above). Basically it results in an averaging of sorts (the integration) and permitted switches to be used in place of expensive power amplifiers (which were different beasts in 'those' days). Anyway, my point is that once the germ of an idea is there, a path often appears...

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of the sine on the unit circle to find that $\sin(A)=\sin(B)$ if either $B=A+2\pi k$ or $B=\pi-A+2\pi k$.

A second, more complicated form of this result can be obtained using trig. identities

$$0=\sin(A)-\sin(B)=2\sin\frac{A-B}2\cos\frac{A+B}2$$

But in the end it is really the same.

Comment: It is not clear to me how this addresses the question?

Comment: There was the idea to determine the cross-over points where $\sin x=\sin 4nx$, i.e., set $A=x$ and $B=4nx$ and find the solutions in $[0,\tfrac\pi2]$.